# Eclipse plugin adding casting of objects

Tags: java, casting, eclipse-plugin

I'm trying to make a cast expression in Eclipse while generating code so I would need something like this:

```
assetType = (AssetType) in.readObject();
```

So I managed to make an assignment expression and set left and right side but I miss this cast, how can I add it?

Heres the code for the above:

```
  Assignment assignmentStatement = fAst.newAssignment();
  assignmentStatement.setLeftHandSide(fAst.newSimpleName(variableBinding.getName()));

  MethodInvocation invoc = fAst.newMethodInvocation();
  invoc.setExpression(fAst.newSimpleName("in"));
  invoc.setName(fAst.newSimpleName("read" + resolveTypeName(variableBinding)));
  invoc.arguments().add(fAst.newSimpleName(IN_PARAMETER_NAME));
  assignmentStatement.setRightHandSide(invoc);
  assignmentStatement.setOperator(Operator.ASSIGN);     

  body.statements().add(fAst.newExpressionStatement(assignmentStatement));
```

Answer (score 0):

Found it: AST.newCastExpresion();